# React clone children & attach props not working

Tags: reactjs

I have this piece of code

```
  render() {
    const { schools, currentSchool, claims } = this.state;
    let loggedIn = this.state.loggedIn ? true : false;
    let user = this.state.user;

      var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child) {
         return React.cloneElement(child, {
             **claims: this.state.claims**
          })
  })
    return (
      <div>
        <HeaderContainer
           user={user}
           claims={claims}
           onLogin={this.onLoginButtonClick} />

        { loggedIn && <NavContainer claims={claims}/> }

          {children}     

        <Footer/>
      </div>
     )
    }
  }
```

however I don't have access to `this.state.claims` for some reason as "this" is undefined . Why is that and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Basic javascript es6, this is nothing to do with reactjs.  Use fat arrow function to keep `this` context.  So in your `React.Children.map` you need to use `(child) => {}` rather than `function(child) {}`.  More here: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can achieve this one is in render function use that = this
`let that = this;`
and then in the function instead of this.state.claims use:

```
return React.cloneElement(child, {//use that variable here } )
```

or the other way you can achieve this is by using arrow function

`var children = this.props.children.map(child => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
        **claims: this.state.claims**
    })`

javascript is all about scope and variables in javascript are function scoped not block scoped. Read more about scope in javascript.